# How to protect web service against unauthorized uses?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security

Recently, I have written a web service for the first time. Now I can get some data from one server in order other web server to use for displaying some statistical data about my organization.

When I write the url on the address bar, service fetches me data in json format.

I have allowed for Httpget and Httppost requests adding lines to web.config file. Now anyone can get that data whenever and wherever they want. I want to use this web service by myself only.

What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be super complex to rather simple. Basically you just need some sort of authentication. Common solutions:

1) secret key to initiate the request. This is done all over the place with RESTful APIs.

2) only specified domains may make the request. Think GMaps API, if you've used that

many more ways if you take a look at what others are doing